# @google-cloud/logging-bunyan not producing the logName i wrote in my code

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, bunyan

I am using the @google-cloud/logging-bunyan (^1.2.3) library with bunyan (^1.8.12) to produce some logs that would be saved to bigquery using a sink. 
I wanted to pass the logName attribute since it is used to create the table (table name). I am doing so since i want to have multiple table for the same backend (nodeJS 8.16.1). 
I carried a test using an app engine and it worked perfectly but after a deployed it to the GKE cluster, it did not print the logName the specified. 
Here is the code snippet i deployed to give you an idea :

```
import bunyan from 'bunyan';
import { LoggingBunyan } from '@google-cloud/logging-bunyan';

const loggingBunyan = new LoggingBunyan({
  logName: 'driver-status-location', // table name
});
export const driverLocationStatusLogger = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: 'yassir-backend-main-log',
  streams: [
    // Log to the console at 'info' and above
    { stream: process.stdout, level: 'info' },
    // And log to Stackdriver Logging, logging at 'info' and above
    loggingBunyan.stream('info'),
  ],
});

export const customDriverLocationStatusLogger = (action, metadata) =>{ 
    driverLocationStatusLogger.info({ labels: { action }, metadata});
}
```

and here is the format of the log i got :

```
{
 insertId: "hecxukciyeulfqocw"  
 jsonPayload: {…}  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/xxx-xx-xx/logs/stdout"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-10T09:10:16.034265465Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "INFO"  
 timestamp: "2019-10-10T09:10:15.292Z"  
}
```

as you see logName is not the one i specified. 
What do you think the problem is ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you see in App engine as you said it's working fine to compare with GKE? Also, I've found this similar [github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan/issues/238#issuecomment-449455466)  that may help you.

Comment: no it is not similar. the guys from that thread is talking about severity level, i am talking about the logName attribute : it should be logName: "projects/swift-implement-155307/logs/driver-status-location  since i used logName: 'driver-status-location' but it is logName: "projects/swift-implement-155307/logs/stdout instead

Comment: Ok i found the solution (the problem) and i would like to share it. for some reason when i use GKE, there is always two similar logs the only difference is that one is generated from my code (@google-cloud/logging-bunyan) and the other come from somewhere else (maybe the fluentd) so now i am using an extra line in the filter (filtering using logName) to get only the logs from my code. Hope that would help someone having the same problem